# Geoserver API - Move layer to different workspace

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-manager

Is it possible to move raster layer with coverage store to different workspace using geoserver rest api?

I suspect that i can remove layer and publish it again but maybe there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create $NEWWORKSPACE in webmanager
2. move datadir/workspaces/$WORKSPACE/$DATASTORE to datadir/workspaces/$NEWWORKSPACE/$DATASTORE (or a subset of layers)
3. Edit datadir/workspaces/$NEWWORKSPACE/$DATASTORE/datastore.xml with the new WORKSPACE ID and new namespace (two fields)
4. Edit for all layers: datadir/workspaces/$NEWWORKSPACE/$DATASTORE/$LAYER/featuretype.xml with new NAMESPACE ID
5. reload resources and config